# What are the default video formats which can be played with a default XP installation?

Tags: windows-xp, video, media, file-format

I'm trying to convert some video files on Linux which can be played on what I assume is a default installation of Windows XP. I don't have access to the machine they will be played on, and the user who will play them doesn't have admin rights to install new codecs or media players.

I have tried .mpeg, which didn't work. I assume .wmv would be a possibility, but I'm finding it difficult to find a way to convert .mpeg to .wmv on Linux.

Are there other media formats which should be playable on a default installation of Windows XP?

Comment: I think mpeg1, but not mpeg2 (DVD format etc) would work on the default XP installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has an extensive list in their [knowledge-base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899113) detailing all of the codecs installed with Windows Media Player 9 & 10, the default for XP.

I would probably suggest one of the following:

- WMV
- Microsoft MPEG-4 (AKA VC1)
- MJPEG

Comment: note that's not "fresh install" default.  XP originally came with WMP 7, i believe.  i think 9 got forcibly installed with SP2 if you hadn't updated it already.

Comment: Did XP necessarily have WMP at all? The copy of Windows 7 that I got from work didn't have WMP preinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

if u can't install a player or codecs u can use MPlayer (just download, un-zip, create a shortcut to mplayer and drop a video file on it or associate to that extension). This player has build-in all codecs you need and u don't need to install (so, u don't have to be an admin)

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html